# Coherent Noise function producing dissimilar results for similar inputs

Tags: noise

Is there a noise function `I(x,y)` which produces dissimilar output for similar inputs?
The primary purpose of it would be to mask coordinates so any point could have a unique value inside the given range.

Comment: hash functions?

Comment: Well. the other question might be describing this better... I think I'll delete this one as it more or less a duplicate... :) Thank you for your input though, it was food for thought!